# Functions that commute with the Laplacian

Tags: harmonic-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, laplacian

I recently read in [Bergeron's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-27666-3) that, for geometric reasons, the hyperbolic Laplacian $$\Delta = -y^2\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)$$ commutes with the isometries $g \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ of the upper-half plane, in the sense that $$\Delta L_g = L_g \Delta$$
where $(L_gf)(z) := f(g(z))$.

I tried to show this fact directly, and I found that any holomorphic function $g(z)$ with $v(z) := \Im(g(z))$ satisfying $$v(z)^2 = y^2|\nabla v|^2$$
also commutes with the Laplacian.

This made me wonder, are there more harmonic functions $v(z)$ besides $\Im(g(z)), g \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, satisfying this?

Thanks in advance!